# Reputation Question

Tags: support, reputation

My answer to [Is Hal fearless at the end of Green Lantern?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/is-hal-fearless-at-the-end-of-green-lantern) shows in my daily reputation score with a '+2'.

It has 1 upvote, and no downvotes.

I didn't ask the question, and it's not the accepted answer.

Is there a reason I got +2 rep instead of +10 for an upvoted answer?

Is this all part of Keen's dastardly plan to stay ahead of me in reputation? ;-)

Edit: As Requested, here's my reputation screen.

[image: Jeff's Reputation for Today]

Comment: You might want to post a screenshot of you getting a +2 for that upvote.  That's pretty weird.  ...And *totally* not part of my plan.  You'll know my plan when you see it in action!

Comment: @Keen: Done.  And your plan is DOOMED.  DOOMED, I tell you.

Comment: BBlake, who also posted an answer on that question and received 1 upvote, has +10 for that.

Comment: I gave up on beating you guys' reputation a long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a “reputation cap”. Roughly speaking, reputation gains from upvotes are capped at 200 per day, or in other words, you only get reputation from your first 10 answer upvotes, or 20 question upvotes, or a mixture of both, of the day. (A day is a calendar day, from 00:00 UTC to 00:00 UTC.)

More precisely, whenever you gain reputation from an upvote, 10 points are added to your day's reputation, up to a total of 200. Today, you had 28 answer upvotes and 4 question upvotes (so far); at some point your total reached 200, so you stopped gaining reputation from upvotes; then you had a downvote, brining you back to 198; then you received another upvote, raising you once again to 200. This explains why you got +2 for that upvote.

Bounties, accepted answers, and the -1 penalty for casting a downvote do not count against the reputation cap.

For more information, see the [Stack Exchange reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and the posts it links.

Comment: *facepalm*  I completely forgot there was a reputation cap.  I guess it's been a while since I hit it.